# Regular expression to match string starting with a specific word

Tags: regex

How do I create a regular expression to match a word at the beginning of a string?

We are looking to match *stop* at the beginning of a string and anything can follow it.

For example, the expression should match:

```
stop
stop random
stopping
```

Answer (score 336):

If you wish to match only lines beginning with *stop*, use

```
^stop
```

If you wish to match lines beginning with the word *stop* followed by a space:

```
^stop\s
```

Or, if you wish to match lines beginning with the word *stop*, but followed by either a space or any other non-word character you can use (your regex flavor permitting)

```
^stop\W
```

On the other hand, what follows matches a word at the beginning of a string on most regex flavors (in these flavors *\w* matches the opposite of *\W*)

```
^\w
```

If your flavor does not have the *\w* shortcut, you can use

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

Be wary that this second idiom will only match letters and numbers, no symbol whatsoever.

Check your regex flavor manual to know what shortcuts are allowed and what exactly do they match (and how do they deal with Unicode).

Answer (score 135):

Try this:

```
/^stop.*$/
```

Explanation:

- **/** charachters delimit the regular expression (i.e. they are not part of the Regex per se)
- **^** means match at the beginning of the line
- **.** followed by ***** means match any character (.), any number of times (*)
- **$** means to the end of the line

If you would like to enforce that stop be followed by a whitespace, you could modify the RegEx like so:

```
/^stop\s+.*$/
```

- **\s** means any whitespace character
- **+** following the **\s** means there has to be at least one whitespace character following after the stop word

Note: Also keep in mind that the RegEx above requires that the stop word be followed by a space! So it wouldn't match a line that only contains: *stop*

Comment: Not all languages use forwardslashes to delimit regexes.

Comment: @Cat Megex: Which is precisely why I added the explanation. If your language uses something else to delimit the regex, replace the / with the proper character

Comment: @Mez yes, and such redundancy increases both clarity and performance http://www.rexegg.com/regex-optimizations.html#anchors

Comment: This didnt work for me....
Command: iostat -dx | awk ' $1 == "/^ada.*$/" { print $1 }'

Comment: Do not use `$` as `.` will match till the end of the line anyway. And if you need to allow more options than just one `stop`, you may use a group: `/^(?:stop|one|or|another|word|here).*/`

Answer (score 62):

If you want to match anything after a word, *stop*, and not only at the start of the line, you may use: `\bstop.*\b` - [word followed by a line](https://regex101.com/r/xB8uW2/1).

[image: Word till the end of string]

Or if you want to match the word in the string, use `\bstop[a-zA-Z]*` - [only the words starting with *stop*](https://regex101.com/r/xB8uW2/11).

[image: Only the words starting with stop]

Or the start of lines with *stop* - `^stop[a-zA-Z]*` for the word only - [first word only](https://regex101.com/r/xB8uW2/12).
The whole line `^stop.*` - [first line of the string only](https://regex101.com/r/xB8uW2/15).

And if you want to match every string starting with stop, including newlines, use: `/^stop.*/s` - [multiline string starting with stop](https://regex101.com/r/xB8uW2/14).

Comment: If needing todo this with JS and some dynamic input causing you to need to use `new RegExp` it is important to know to escape the boundary (or any other flags), for example for the "stop" sample here: `new RegExp('\\b' + varStringStop + '\\w')`

Answer (score 27):

Using the **caret** won't match every word beginning with "**stop**".

Only if it's at the beginning of a line like "**stop going**".
@Waxo gave the right answer:

This one is ***slightly*** better, if you want to match any word beginning with "**stop**" and containing nothing but letters from ***A to Z***.

```
\bstop[a-zA-Z]*\b
```

This would match all

> **stop** (1)
>
> **stop** random (2)
>
> **stopping** (3)
>
> want to **stop** (4)
>
> please **stop** (5)

While

```
/^stop[a-zA-Z]*/
```

would only match (1) until (3), but not (4) & (5)

Comment: There is no one by the name "SharadHolani" here (incl. deleted answers). What answer does it refer to?

Answer (score 9):

If you want to match anything that starts with "stop" including "stop going", "stop" and "stopping" use:

```
^stop
```

If you want to match the *word* stop followed by anything as in "stop going", "stop this", but not "stopped" and not "stopping" use:

```
^stop\W
```

Answer (score 8):

```
/stop([a-zA-Z])+/
```

Will match any stop word (stop, stopped, stopping, etc)

However, if you just want to match "stop" at the start of a string

```
/^stop/
```

will do :D

Comment: This will match "don't stop going"

Comment: This will not match stop123 or stop,.

Answer (score 4):

If you want the word to start with "stop", you can use the following pattern. 
"^stop.*"

This will match words starting with stop followed by anything.

Comment: Could you not just use `"^stop"`?

Comment: It depends. While talking in terms of java syntax, we can use Pattern and Matcher object for using regex or direct use .matches() method with String object.  They differ in result as below:  

`code`
    `String line = "stopped";`
    `String pattern = "^stop";`
    `Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);`
    `Matcher m = r.matcher(line);`
    `System.out.println(m.find( ));  //prints true`
    `System.out.println(line.matches(pattern));  //prints false`

Comment: This matches only if the word at the beginning of the line.
If words beginning with "stop" are in the middle of the line or at the end, this regex won't match.

@StephenRauch if you omit [a-z]* you wouldn't get any words like "stopping" in whole. In the case of "stopping" you get "stop" and "ping" would be missing.

Answer (score 2):

```
/^stop*$/i
```

*i* - in case it is case sensitive.

Comment: `p*` means any number of `p`s and only `p`s, including 0.

Answer (score 1):

can you try this:

`https://regex101.com/r/P3qfKG/1`

reg = `/stop(\w+| [^ ]+|$)/gm`

it will select both stop and start with stop and next word;

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/P3qfKG/1

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise against a simple regular expression approach to this problem. There are too many words that are substrings of other unrelated words, and you'll probably drive yourself crazy trying to overadapt the simpler solutions already provided.

You'll want at least a naive stemming algorithm (try the Porter stemmer; there's available, free code in most languages) to process text first. Keep this processed text and the preprocessed text in two separate space-split arrays. Make sure each non-alphabetical character also gets its own index in this array. Whatever list of words you're filtering, stem them also.

The next step would be to find the array indices which match to your list of stemmed 'stop' words. Remove those from the unprocessed array, and then rejoin on spaces.

This is only slightly more complicated, but will be much more reliable an approach.  If you've got any doubts on the value of a more NLP-oriented approach, you might want to do some research into [clbuttic mistakes](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The-Clbuttic-Mistake-.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Based on @MikeDinescu regex, if you want to match also `Stop` and `sTop` use with ignore case use the flag i for ignore case / case unsensitive:

**JavaScript:**

```
const pattern = /^stop.*$/i
```

**Python:**

```
pattern = re.compile(r"^stop.*$", re.IGNORECASE)
```

**PHP:**

```
$pattern = '/^stop.*$/i'
```

[Regex DEMO](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/170d6197e7e5).