# Searching XCode for strings starting with _

Tags: regex, xcode

I read: 
[Regular Expression to match string starting with "stop"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240504/regular-expression-to-match-string-starting-with-stop)

I want to search for all strings starting with a `_` character using regex search in XCode (in case that matters) which I initially thought I would be able to search for with ^_ but that only returns me lines that start with _ they exclude lines with spaces.

I would like my search to return all of the following:

```
_foo
 _bar
  _baz
```

for example and exclude things like

```
foo_bar 
#_
  wholeWord_anotherWord
```

or any other string that doesnt start with '_' followed by myString (ex _myString is a desired result). Basically I'm looking for all variables following the _ naming convention.

I read: [How to ignore whitespace in a regular expression subject string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590298/how-to-ignore-whitespace-in-a-regular-expression-subject-string)

I tried `"\s*^_"` but that returned me only `'new line'_aString`. Did I misunderstand the solution? What will give me the correct response of any _variable?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that finds things like ,_bar foo_baz etc.

Comment: It matches whole words starting with _ and then having one or more letters, digits or underscores. I do not think your specifications are clear, so I just suggested something that sounds similar. It doesn't have to work for you, of course, it is just a shot in the dark.

Comment: \b_\w+ for me in xcode using regex search returns whole words that do not start with _. For example it returns me foo_bar.

Comment: Hm, does it support lokbehinds? Try `(?<!\w)_\w+`

Comment: Your solution returns _foo and  /_foo. After looking at the results it lets in the desired results and results starting with /.

Comment: These results do not make sense actually. Well, you may tell the regex engine to ignore those with `/` like this: `(?<![\w/])_\w+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I initially thought I would be able to search for with ^_ but that only returns me lines that start with _ they exclude lines with spaces

Given that:

- You say `^_` works for the lines that don't start with spaces; and
- You wish you exclude lines such as foo_bar, (or `" foo_bar"` for that matter)
- You are using the Xcode regex search box

Then I have found any of the following combinations:

- `^\s*_`
- `^\s+?_`
- `^[:space:]*_`

Will return matches for each of the following:

```
_foo
 _bar
  _baz
```

Note that the `[:space:]` character class accounts for all whitespace (tabs, form feeds, carriage return, etc).

You can return the entire string that starts with any of these criteria by adding `(.*$)` to the above regex' respectively;

- `(^\s*_\w+)(\s*)(.*$)`
- `(^\s+?_\w+)(\s*)(.*$)`
- `(^[:space:]*_\w+)([:space:]*)(.*$)`

If separation is required then the back reference `\1` would be `_var` and back reference `\3` would be the string after the `_var` if separated by a whitespace.

Comment: How did you make the `[:space:]` POSIX character class use outside a bracket expression? It will never work as expected. `[:space:]` as such will be parsed as an NFA character class and will match a single `:`. or `s`, `p`, `a`, `c`, or `e` char.