# Regex to match multiple instances of a string

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to extract a set of strings from a consul output. 
What I want to do is remove all instances of the strings which start with

```
/usr/lib/ocf/resource.d/
```

**Input String**

```
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 971 Sep 22 13:15 /usr/lib/ocf/resource.d/cloud_init_ocf.sh/n-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 662 Aug 28 11:25 /usr/lib/ocf/resource.d/credentialmanagercliRestartVM.sh/n-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 843 Sep 28 11:13 /usr/lib/ocf/resource.d/jboss_healthcheck.sh
```

In the above example string that would be the strings of

```
/usr/lib/ocf/resource.d/cloud_init_ocf.sh
/usr/lib/ocf/resource.d/credentialmanagercliRestartVM.sh
/usr/lib/ocf/resource.d/jboss_healthcheck.sh
```

**What I have tried**

I have tried to match the Strings which start with 
`\\b/usr/lib/ocf/resource.d/.*\\b`
[I got from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240504/regular-expression-to-match-string-starting-with-stop)

**Code**

```
 regexChecker("\\b/usr/lib/ocf/resource.d/.*\\b", output);

    private ArrayList<String> regexChecker(String regEx, String str2Check) {
        final ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        Pattern checkRegex = Pattern.compile(regEx);
        Matcher regexMatcher = checkRegex.matcher(str2Check);
        String regexMatch;
        while (regexMatcher.find()) {
            if (regexMatcher.group().length() != 0) {
                regexMatch = regexMatcher.group();
                result.add(regexMatch);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I think the issue is the `/n` character which is inserted at the end of each line.

Comment: So, effectively, you want to "replace" certain Strings. Right?

Comment: try `/usr/lib/ocf/resource.d/.*` ref

Comment: is your input string really without newlines?

Comment: @TheLostMind the way i think about it is, I want to extract a string from with in a sub string.

Comment: @GUIDO I am not sure what you mean by with out newlines. The input string contains newlines at the end of each line -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 971 Sep 22 13:15 /usr/lib/ocf/resource.d/cloud_init_ocf.sh/n

Comment: The input string in your question contains no linefeed, instead it contains the two characters `/n` where you would expect a linefeed. While `\n` is a way to represent the Line Feed character, `/n` are just two characters without any special meaning.

Comment: Anyway you're using word-boundaries wrong by using them around non-word characters : using a `\b` before the `/` in your pattern means it must be preceded by a word character (since a word boundary is the boundary between a word and something else, and that `/` isn't a word character, so it must be the 'something else' and must be preceded by a word)

Comment: try this regex `(\/usr\/lib\/ocf\/resource\.d\/[a-zA-Z_]*(\.sh[\s|]?)?)`

Comment: @RahmatWaisi That worked great. Some of the strings end in .bsh also.

Comment: @RahmatWaisi so I added (\.sh|\.bsh[\s|]?)?) and it worked fine. thanks again.

Comment: @RahmatWaisi create an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @SeanMcGrath you're welcome, ok, sorry i was busy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this way

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String regex = "(\\/usr\\/lib\\/ocf\\/resource\\.d\\/[a-zA-Z_]*(\\.sh[\\s|]?)?)";
        String string = "-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 971 Sep 22 13:15 /usr/lib/ocf/resource.d/cloud_init_ocf.sh/n-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 662 Aug 28 11:25 /usr/lib/ocf/resource.d/credentialmanagercliRestartVM.sh/n-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 843 Sep 28 11:13 /usr/lib/ocf/resource.d/jboss_healthcheck.sh";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
        int i =1;
        while (matcher.find()) {
                System.out.println("Group " + i++ + ": " + matcher.group(0));
        }
    }
}
```

and output is

```
Group 1: /usr/lib/ocf/resource.d/cloud_init_ocf.sh
Group 2: /usr/lib/ocf/resource.d/credentialmanagercliRestartVM.sh
Group 3: /usr/lib/ocf/resource.d/jboss_healthcheck.sh
```