# Extracting text from string using Regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a very large string. There are many paragraphs inside that string. Each paragraph starts with a **title** and follows a **particular pattern.**

Example:

`== Title1 == // Paragraph starts
.............
............. // Some texts
.............
End of Paragraph
===Title2 === // Paragraph starts
.............
............. // Some texts
.............`

The pattern of the title are:

> 1.) New Paragraph ***title*** starts with an equal to ( = ) and can be followed by any number of =.
>
> 2.) After = , there can be a white space ( not necessary though ) and it is followed by text.
>
> 3.) After text completion, again there can be a white space ( not necessary ), followed by again any number of equal to's ( = ).
>
> 4.) Now the paragraph starts. I have to extract the text until it encounters a similar pattern.

Can anyone help me with how to do this with regex? TIA

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I was trying this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240504/regular-expression-to-match-string-starting-with-stop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
re.findall(r'(?m)^=+[^\S\r\n]*(.*?)[^\S\r\n]*=+\s*(.*(?:\r?\n(?!=+.*?=).*)*)', s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pGijuI/2)

**Details**

- `(?m)^` - start of a line
- `=+` - 1 or more `=` chars
- `[^\S\r\n]*` - zero or more whitespace chars other than CR and LF
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars, other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `[^\S\r\n]*` - zero or more whitespace chars other than CR and LF
- `=+` - 1 or more `=` chars
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(.*(?:\r?\n(?!==+.*?=).*)*)` - Group 2:

  - `.*` - any zero or more chars, other than line break chars, as many as possible
  - `(?:\r?\n(?!=+.*?=).*)*` - zero or more sequences of

    - `\r?\n(?!=+.*?=)` - an optional CR and then LF that is not followed with 1+ `=`s, then any chars other than line break chars as few as possible and then again 1+ `=`s
    - `.*` - any zero or more chars, other than line break chars, as many as possible

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/GmfPRp):

```
import re

rx = r"(?m)^=+[^\S\r\n]*(.*?)[^\S\r\n]*=+\s*(.*(?:\r?\n(?!=+.*?=).*)*)"
s = "== Title1 ==\n..........................\n.............\nEnd of Paragraph\n===Title2 ===\n.............\n.............\n............."
print(re.findall(rx, s))
```

Output:

```
[('Title1', '..........................\n.............\nEnd of Paragraph'), ('Title2', '.............\n.............\n.............')]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try this -

```
x = "== Title1   ==="
ptrn = "[=]{1,}[\s]{0,}[\w]+[\s]{0,}[=]{1,}"
if re.search(ptrn, x):
    x = x.replace('=', '').strip()
```

Will give you `Title1`. Or suppose you wanted all the matching titles in a list, you could do -

```
x = '== Title1   ===nansnsk fnasasklsanlkas lkaslkans \n== Title2 ==='
titles = [i.replace('=', '').strip() for i in re.findall(ptrn, x)]
# OP ['Title1', 'Title2']
```

The pattern is -

```
"^[=]{1,}[\s]{0,}[\w]+[\s]{0,}[=]{1,}"
```

> ^[=]{1,} - match at least one equal sign at the start
>
> [\s]{0,} - match between zero to unlimited equal signs
>
> [\w]+ - match [a-zA-Z0-9_] once or more

After which we can extract text from this by replacing `=` with `''` and stripping it off spaces. You could try it at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/XWwYi1/1) which is really helpful when testing regex

Comment: Thanks a lot! I upvoted your answer, but I found the last answer most suitable, hence i accepted it.

Answer (score 2):

May be this helps for finding each paragraphs Title and lines of each paragraph.

```
text = """== Title1 == // Paragraph starts
.............
............. // Some texts
.............
End of Paragraph
===Title2 === // Paragraph starts
.............
............. // Some texts
.............
"""
import re

reg = re.compile(r'(?:[=]+\s*\w+\s*[=]+)')

for i in text.split('\n'):
    if re.search(reg, i):
        t = re.sub(r'=', '', i)
        print('Title:', t.strip())
    else:
        print('line:', i.strip())

 # Output like this
   Title: Title1  // Paragraph starts
   line: .............
   line: ............. // Some texts
   line: .............
   line: End of Paragraph
   Title: Title2  // Paragraph starts
   line: .............
   line: ............. // Some texts
   line: .............
   line:
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I upvoted your answer, but I found the last answer most suitable, hence i accepted it.

Answer (score 1):

> 1.) New Paragraph title starts with an equal to ( = ) and can be followed by any number of =.

This can be represented by `=+`.

> 2.) After = , there can be a white space ( not necessary though ) and it is followed by text.
>
> 3.) After text completion, again there can be a white space ( not necessary ), followed by again any number of equal to's ( = ).

So the pattern for the title becomes: `=+[^=]+=+\n`, which means, match at least one `=`, then some text not including `=`, then again at least one `=`.

Catching everything between those patterns will give you desired text.

In below pattern, whole match includes title, first group contains the text.

So finally, your pattern wuld be: `=+[^=]+=+\n([\w\W]+\n)(?==+[^=]+=+\n)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XBSaMT/1)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I upvoted your answer, but I found the last answer most suitable, hence i accepted it.