# transform a column based on startwith function in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a data frame column that contains text like this

```
col

    0     abc-text1
    1     def_text2-
```

What I would like to do with pyspark is that if my col startswith 'abc-' then replace it with just 'abc' and if it starts with 'def_'  then replace it with def.

I would like to create a function for the same. I am fairley new to python and pyspark thus need help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pyspark regexp_replace for this, see code below.

```
# This replaces all - and _
data = [(1,"abc-text1"), (2,"def_text1-")]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data, ["a","b"])
dfe  = df.withColumn("b_1", F.regexp_replace(F.col("b"), "(-|_)", ""))
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your column name is col1, and dataframe is df,

```
df = df.withColumn('col1', regexp_replace(col('col1'), "^abc", "abc"))
df = df.withColumn('col1', regexp_replace(col('col1'), "^def", "def"))
```

You can use regular expressions (example here: [Regular Expression to match string starting with "stop"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240504/regular-expression-to-match-string-starting-with-stop)) to replace the value starting with 'abc' or 'def' with 'def'.