# How not to remove first number in the sentence and remove later occurances of numbers in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I have a sentence that consists of numbers and words. I am looking for a solution to remove numbers except at the beginning. I have tried the following code, but it's removing all the numbers.

```
x = '45 is fourth five 45 when 9 and 5 are multiplied'

re.sub('\d', '', x)
```

Its output was

```
'is Fourth five when and are multiplied'
```

But need the output in the following manner.

```
'45 is Fourth five when and are multiplied'
```

Note:

1. The number may or may not present at the beginning.
2. Inside the sentence, there can be alphanumeric (`460KG`), then it should be changed (KG). That means, except at the beginning, the number should be removed elsewhere.
   example :

```
6-apples price is 56Rs
```

I need an output as

```
6-apples price is Rs
```

Comment: Expected vs. desired. You have not shown any attempt to get the desired output, so saying it's expected is effectively looking for free code.

Comment: @Raghu this SO question and its answers should be sufficient information for you to solve this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240504/regular-expression-to-match-string-starting-with-stop

Comment: Also, your problem is not clearly defined. For example, does the number always appear in the first character, or can it appear after arbitrary non-numeric sequences?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @AMC and MadPhysicist I have improved the explanation, hope its sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Pypi regex library](https://pypi.org/project/regex/), you can do:

```
import regex

x = '45 is fourth five 45 when 9 and 5 are multiplied'
print regex.sub(r'(?<=\D*\d+\D+)\d+ ?', '', x)
```

**Output:**

```
45 is fourth five when and are multiplied
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=        # positive lookbehind, make sure we have before:
    \D*         # 0 or more non digits
    \d+         # 1 or more digits
    \D+         # 1 or more non digits
)           # end lookbehind
\d+         # 1 or more digits
 ?          # optional space
```

Answer (score 1):

*You can use this:*

```
x = '45 is fourth five 45 when 9 and 5 are multiplied'

string = re.sub(r'(?<!^)\b\d+\s', '', x)
```

*Result:*

```
>>> print(string)

45 is fourth five when and are multiplied
```

Comment: That first `\s` looks suspicious

Comment: This is a partial solution, it doesn't work in all cases. For instance, it will remove the first occurrence of 45 if the sentence starts with a letter.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Right :).

Comment: @BobEzuba The OP had't asked for such kind of case.